# Putting flat texture on the box

Tags: uv

I am creating an architecture model. I have stairs modelled as simple boxes for each step. The single step is multiplied using array modifier and this way I have stairs.
But the question is about texture mapping. I have flat texture and I want to achieve the result that the single step has continuous mapping on each side. When I unwrap it, only single corners are connected. How to do it correctly and in easy way (to do not modify the texture)?

Comment: Hello, I would say make sure that the UV seams are correct but maybe show some screenshots?

Comment: A step with continuous mapping on each side? It not only depends on correct UVs but also on the texture - some textures cannot be continuous on each side (or you phrased that mistakable). For example, let's say you a simple box and the texture is a simple 45° degree striped pattern. When you want it to be continuous from the top face to the front face this works. From top face to the side face this works too. But then the side face to the front face can never be continuous with a pattern like this. So it would be helpful to know what texture it is and what you mean by continuous on each side.

Comment: I think it would greatly help us understand this question precisely, if you could show us a picture of  the unsatisfactory result.